# How to unlock account set on fingerprint without fingerprint

Tags: login, password, scanner, authentication

I'm using fingerprint scanner to log in or authenticate my account.
I've enabled it by running command:

```
$ sudo pam-auth-update
```

and then selecting fingerprint authentication.
I've cut my finger badly so my laptop fingerprint can't recognize it and now, I can login into my device by password but I cannot do anything that needs administrator permission or I cannot run any sudo command.

What should I do? Is anyway to disable it?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you try to enroll another finger? And you should still be able to use the password.

Comment: I hav'nt add another finger. How can I do it?

Comment: The same way you did the first time?!? But again, you should be able to use the password as well.

Comment: Thanks. But when i click to add any fingerprint, not only does'nt it add any finger print, but it also wants to delete my saved fingerprint